# Why would you call .detach() on a parameter when the code is within with torch.no_grad()?

Tags: pytorch

So I have this code for updating critic in SAC

```
with torch.no_grad():
            _, policy_action, log_pi, _ = self.actor(next_obs)
            target_Q1, target_Q2 = self.critic_target(next_obs, policy_action)
            target_V = torch.min(target_Q1, target_Q2) - self.alpha.detach() * log_pi
            target_Q = reward + (not_done * self.discount * target_V)
```

this is not my code it's code I got off GitHub. As we can see they have a `torch.no_grad()` and `self.alpha.detach()` why would you need both? This seems redundant to me as `torch.no_grad()` anything within the `with` statement will not be added to the computational graph and `.detach()` does the same thing but for a single variable. Why would you use `torch.no_grad()` and `detach()`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to detach tensors from the graph when under the `torch.no_grad` context manager. However, I suspect this snippet was copied from the inference loop where the gradients are computed by default. You could verify that by navigating the training loop's source file.